# FB query via GraphApi - don't get bio

Tags: facebook-graph-api, permissions

i'm reading some fb-friend-profiles via GraphAPI which works as expected, except that i don't get some "bio" informations about the user. i can read the bio of my own profile, but it won't work for friends.
when i debug the access-token with the AccessTokenDebugger i can see the "user_about_me" and "friends_about_me" permission.

when i'm using the GraphApiExplorer by using the same access-token and select the default "Application" i can get the bio of the requested friend.

-> when i select my own application i can see in the access-token the "friend_about_me" permission, but in the result the bio is missing .... mhmm

IMHO i think that the GraphApi request is correct, but i don't get the correct answer!?

any ideas what can cause this issue?!

br,
alex

Answer (score 0):

I can help you out if you show me the JSON response your application is getting.  You can do this by downloading Fiddler and doing the web request. Fiddler will show you the raw data in the response.  I would like what you see in the 'TextView' of Fiddler when you do the request from your application.

Thanks!

Comment: request:
**GET URL: https://graph.facebook.com/sigrun.winterauer?access_token=AAAC49NSuiEEBAFfag0yH1rdZCosoM2rATZAxWOTLOkIV6PWqpdDat7jwEOeASBDlLdluBa7Brvyt6fSRjxcTZCOKR8FUQVTIDx7FHEqZBAZDZD&format=json**

response:
**{"id":"618816141","name":"Sigrun Winterauer","first_name":"Sigrun","last_name":"Winterauer","link":"http:\/\/www.facebook.com\/sigrun.winterauer","username":"sigrun.winterauer","gender":"female","locale":"de_DE","updated_time":"2011-10-28T14:11:46+0000"}**

br,
alex

Comment: when i use the GraphApiExplorer i can't get the bio from the request above .... when i switch to the default-test-"Graph Api Explorer" i do get the bio ????